How to count primitive Operations
I've been struggling with counting primitive operations. I know that you do not have to outline every operation that happens in your pseudocode but this is never the less a bit complicated for me. Here's my example:
pseudo(n, x)                      1
  a ← x                           1
  if n > 1 then                   n
    for i ← 1? to n do            n
      a ← a + i                  2n
    for k ← 8 to n do             9
      a ← a + pseudo(n/4, a/2)    2
  return a                        1

raster image of text rendered
T(n) = 3n+14 ∈ O(n)
this is how I interpreted this code, as far as I can see these for loops are independent from each other meaning we still have O(n) and not O(n^2) right?
Also unsure what recursion exactly is as an operation. 

Please fix some statements.

Write down the number of primitive operations and the result returned in the cases n=0, n=1.
Write down the number of primitive operations and the return value for 2 <= n <= 7. In the recursive call  the same function is called with the first argument 0 or 1, and you wrote down the primitive operations and result for that case.
Then handle 8 <= n <= 31, 32 <= n <= 127 etc.

There are two problems, one minor, the other major.
1)    for k ← 8 to n do

Not $9$ iterations, but $n-7$.
2)    a ← a + pseudo(n/4, a/2)

There is a recursive call, so you don't just count the instructions, but their total cost. Denoting the complexity of the function as $T(n, x)$, this instruction costs $2 + T(n/4, a/2)$ where $a$ is computed as a function of $n$ and $x$ (in fact $x+n(n+1)/2$). Furthermore, this line is invoked $n-7$ times, with different values of $a$!
IMO, exact evaluation of the complexity is a daunting task.
